# Check if user is logged in on other ADFS authenticated site

Tags: authentication, adfs

I've been looking around for this specific situation, but so far no good..

We have multiple websites that use ADFS WSFederation, and we would like for a user to always pass through one, before being allowed into the other websites.

I couldn't find anything that would help me in this specific case (but my knowledge on ADFS is not too extended, so it could be I've misinterpreted the clues), but what would I have to set so that the scenario below is enforced:

John tries to access site1.com, but is not logged on through ADFS.. John has to authenticate and is being redirected to mainsite.com.
Now John can navigate to site1.com.
Good for John.

If John initially went to mainsite.com, and then to site1.com, there would be no problem..

Any suggestions? The websites are ASP.NET MVC sites if that's any help...